# C# Change 'this' from within object

Tags: c#

This is probably a terrible way of doing things, but here goes anyway...

I want to re-initialise an object from within the object itself.

I have an object called `Quote`, one of the methods is `Calculate()` and it does a lot of things. One thing is that if certain major properties are changed, we call it a Big Change and we need to create a new Quote (not just update the existing one).

In the middle of `Calculate()` it would be really easy (IMO) to just do this:

```
public class Quote {
    public bool Calculate() {

        //... do lots of things

        if(IsBigChange) {
            this = new Quote();
        }

        //... do more things
        // later when it is saved it will be a new quote

    }
}
```

`Calculate()` is called from lots of places, so I don't really want to kick out when Big Change is detected and create the new object 'outside', if you know what I mean.

So if you can't set `this`, is there another way of achieving the same result?

Comment: You can't assign an object to `this`.

Comment: If Calculate() is called from lots of places, I would like to suggest you take a 'Quote' object at application/global level and rather than changing this, change the global variable. I think, it will give you better control over usage and in change of value as well.

Comment: Tell us *why* would you need such requirements? You cannot and definitely don't need to recreate a object from itself.

Comment: Can't you just change the id of Quote and add a isNew property to use to check for insert instead of update?

Comment: 1. Why is it not enough to update the values? 2. It looks like you are missing a level in the class hierarchy. Maybe add the calculate should go one level up, or create a "data" object one level down

Comment: Even if it were possible -- I think early C++ versions allowed it --; what would the semantics be? Any references to the old object would still point to the old object (the object does not go away just because you switch a reference to another object!). Who would know about the new object? I think John Wu's answer is good.

Comment: Btw, I find the downvotes silly. It's a fundamental question. Granted, it has been decided 30 years ago for C++, but it's a legit question.

Comment: @JorgeAltieri that's certainly the easiest way to do what I want here, but the ORM I'm using has no setter on ID. This isn't the first time I've thought of doing this, so I thought I'd find out what I really should be doing

Comment: Proxy the quote interface and redirect all calls to inner real quote object. On the big change simply replace inner object. Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't change `this`. Man, that would be confusing.

That being said, you can *set* `this` (sort of) from a static method, which has no `this` to begin with. You just create a new object and return it. This is a pretty traditional way to do it. Example:

```
class Quote
{
    static public Quote Calculate(int inputData)
    {
        var foo = DoComputations(inputData);
        return new Quote(foo);
    }

    public Quote(Foo foo)
    {
        //Initialize member variables based on the output of the calculations (a.k.a. foo)
    }
}
```

Then instead of calling it like this:

```
var q = new Quote();
q.Calculate(data);
```

You'd do this:

```
var q = Quote.Calculate(data);
```

Comment: I think this is probably the way to go, your earlier version of your answer had me thinking too. The problem was that I'm using database models that are generated and I'd need to make some pretty fundamental changes to a lot of code to do those other changes (and it raises the question of always setting up classes like that just in case you might need to do something like this)

Comment: You can't change this for reference types. For structs you actually can (that is, you can do `this = someStruct` inside a struct).

Comment: Huh! You learn something new every day!  Although I think it is best practices to keep structs immutable.